# Quarkus with JavaFX Demo throws exception when executing function in fxml

Tags: java, javafx, quarkus

I wanted to create a new JavaFX application with Quarkus support. I used this template:

https://github.com/pedrolopix/quarkus-javafx-example

Here's what I did:

1. Cloned the repo.
2. Executed `mvn quarkus:dev`.

   - This causes a JavaFX window to be displayed.
3. Clicked on the "Click!" button

Clicking on the button resulted in the following error, though there are a lot more logs from Quarkus not included here:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
java.lang.InternalError: bouncer cannot be found
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.getTrampoline(MethodUtil.java:312)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.<clinit>(MethodUtil.java:87)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.<clinit>(MethodHelper.java:44)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(String, java.lang.Class[])" because "<local1>" is null
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil$1.run(MethodUtil.java:306)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil$1.run(MethodUtil.java:300)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.getTrampoline(MethodUtil.java:299)
        ... 49 more
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Has a current Quarkus JavaFX demo app?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please stick to one question per post. Please make an attempt at doing the things posted and post a question with what you attempted. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437944/quarkus-application-with-javafx?noredirect=1#comment129692646_73437944.

Comment: Also, I am able to run this in `Netbeans` using `Maven 3.8.5` or `Maven 3.6.3` and `JavaFX 18`. I am not very familiar with `IntelliJ`, but I would start by making sure your it is using one of these versions.

Comment: Did you follow the points listed in How to reproduce?

Comment: I download the project as a Zip from `GitHub`. I made sure I met the requirements in the repo. I open the project in `Netbeans 13`. I click the run in `Netbeans`. The program ran, and I typed my name. I had no errors. If this does not help you, be more clear with your explanation.

Comment: You forgot the last step. You need to type the name and click the "Click me button" to the right of the textfield.

Comment: Yea, I did that.

Comment: Ok that’s weird. I use the latest Java and Maven Version (18 and 3.8.6). Please start it from Terminal with mvn quarkus:dev so we can exclude the IDE as error source.

Comment: Have you been to https://github.com/pedrolopix/quarkus-javafx-example? Are you following the instructions laid out there? That page is requiring `JKD 11+`, `Maven 3.6.3+` and telling you to run `mvn package` and `java -jar target/quarkus-javafx-example-1.0-runner.jar`. I don't see anywhere where it says to use `mvn quarkus:dev`.

Comment: Also, it seems the run it command is off. It should be `java -jar ./target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`

Comment: I've edited your question to make it flow better (in my opinion) and to show the full stack trace. Let me know if I made any errors.

Comment: However, as noted by @SedJ601 and in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437944/quarkus-application-with-javafx?noredirect=1#comment129692646_73437944) on your original question, it is possible to get the application to run (though perhaps not in "dev mode" or whatever `quarkus:dev` does).

Comment: __DO NOT__ delete and repost a question - instead edit the previous to make it answerable

Comment: Alright thanks @SedJ601 and Slaw for checking this out. Developing an application like this is quite hard when you have to type in those two commands every single time. I hoped there was a more elegant way of running a Quarkus JavaFX application. I managed to get around the problem by getting rid of the fxml part.

Comment: @kleopatra The original post didn't get a reopen after detailing the post  from an editor within 10 hours and since it was stated right at the top to either edit the question or delete and ask a new question I decided to delete the original question and ask in a more precise way again.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows 11.